# CSS3 animation is not working on safari browser

Tags: css, safari

I have animation and there is a problem that on safari browser animation is not working, how to fix this problem? Below is my snippet:

```css
.logo, .logo::before, .logo::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background: url('/images/logo.png') no-repeat 50% / 70% rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    color: #f92d2d;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f92d2d;
}

.logo::before, .logo::after {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    margin: -5%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
    animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
}

.logo::before {
    animation-delay: -4s;
}

@keyframes clipMe {
    0%, 100% {
        clip: rect(0px, 165px, 2px, 0px);
    }
    25% {
        clip: rect(0px, 2px, 165px, 0px);
    }
    50% {
        clip: rect(163.5px, 165px, 165px, 0px);
    }
    75% {
        clip: rect(0px, 165px, 165px, 163.5px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

On other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge works perfectly fine.

Comment: Either way, that property is deprecated and will eventually stop working in all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Comment: Instead you should use `clip-path`, though it isn't supported by Safari yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path